# HTTP 403 when installing Azure Pack Express

Tags: azure

I'm trying to install an instance of Windows Azure Pack and it unfortunately fails towards the end with an HTTP 403 error message (after following the Microsoft [prerequisites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn469335.aspx) and the [Express Install](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn296439.aspx) guide to the letter) at the URL: `https://localhost:30091/#Workspaces/WebSystemAdminExtension/quickStart`.

In summary, I get to [Figure 15](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/cloud-computing/deploying-windows-azure-pack-part6.html) fine but I do not get the dialog box shown on Figure 16. I instead get the error message after clicking "Continue to this website (not recommended)."

[image: Azure Express Install Error Message]

Can anybody explain what is happening here? I have checked the directory permissions and everything looks in order.

**UPDATE**: I have also tried accessing the management portal for tenants and see the same result at the URL: `https://localhost:30081/#Workspaces/All/dashboard`.

**UPDATE**: It turns out it was my proxy; see the answer below. Thanks for everybody's comments.

Comment: Have you tried logging off and back on again as your linked tutorial suggests in the event of Access Denied? Also, have you checked the Windows Credential Manager to ensure you don't have any saved credentials for localhost?

Comment: I have logged in and logged out, rebooted and rebooted; all to no effect. I have just checked the Windows Credential Manager and nothing is in there. Also, it isn't actually an "Access Denied", it's the website refusing to show, hence my confusion because the Express install handles the site installation and configuration.

Comment: **Why are the ports different?**  In one figure its 30101 in another its 30091 that does not make any technical sense.  Verify the services require are running.

Comment: Azure installs *lots* and *lots* of sites in IIS and each one does something different. I *think* the 30091 is where the main Administration site is configured and then subsequently accessed. But, in any case, I am accessing the correct site/port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I configured our company proxy in Internet Explorer and used this to download all of the updates from Microsoft. I turned off the proxy and all of a sudden it worked. I'm perhaps more confused now because it allowed me to configure everything else with the proxy enabled, so why not these particular sites? Very weird.